# Using external optimizers with tensorflow and stochastic network elements

Tags: tensorflow

I have been using Tensorflow with the l-bfgs optimizer from openopt. It was pretty easy to setup callbacks to allow Tensorflow to compute gradients and loss evaluations for the l-bfgs, however, I am having some trouble figuring out how to introduce stochastic elements like dropout into the training procedure.

During the line search, l-bfgs performs multiple evaluations of the loss function, which need to operate on the same network as the prior gradient evaluation. However, it seems that for each evaluation of the tf.nn.dropout function, a new set of dropouts is created. I am looking for a way to fix the dropout over multiple evaluations of the loss function, and then allow it to change between the gradient steps of the l-bfgs. I'm assuming this has something to do with the control flow ops in tensorflow, but there isn't really a good tutorial on how to use these and they are a little enigmatic to me.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drop-out relies on uses `random_uniform` which is a stateful op, and I don't see a way to reset it. However, you can hack around it by substituting your own random numbers and feeding them to the same input point as `random_uniform`, replacing the generated values

Taking the following code:

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
graph_level_seed = 1
operation_level_seed = 1
tf.set_random_seed(graph_level_seed)
b = tf.nn.dropout(a, 0.5, seed=operation_level_seed)
```

Visualize the graph to see where `random_uniform` is connected

[image: visualization of dropout]

You can see `dropout` takes input of `random_uniform` through the `Add` op which has a name `mydropout/random_uniform/(random_uniform)`. Actually the `/(random_uniform)` suffix is there for UI reasons, and the true name is `mydropout/random_uniform` as you can see by printing `tf.get_default_graph().as_graph_def()`. That gives you shortened tensor name. Now you append `:0` to get actual tensor name. (side-note: operation could produce multiple tensors which correspond to suffixes `:0`, `:1` etc. Since having one output is the most common case, `:0` is implicit in GraphDef and `node` input is equivalent to `node:0`. However `:0` is not implicit when using `feed_dict` so you have to explicitly write `node:0`)

So now you can fix the seed by generating your own random numbers (of the same shape as incoming tensor), and reusing them between invocations.

```
tf.reset_default_graph()
a = tf.constant([1, 1, 1, 1, 1], dtype=tf.float32)
graph_level_seed = 1
operation_level_seed = 1
tf.set_random_seed(graph_level_seed)
b = tf.nn.dropout(a, 0.5, seed=operation_level_seed, name="mydropout")
random_numbers = np.random.random(a.get_shape()).astype(dtype=np.float32)
sess = tf.Session()
print sess.run(b, feed_dict={"mydropout/random_uniform:0":random_numbers})
print sess.run(b, feed_dict={"mydropout/random_uniform:0":random_numbers})
```

You should see the same set of numbers with 2 run calls.